Number of Replicas in Statistical Thermodynamics
Am reading Sears and Salinger "Thermodynamics, Kinetic Theory, and Statistical Thermodynamics".  And getting confused when they compute the Group Average Value $\overline{N}^g_j$ of the Occupation Number at Energy Level $j$ in macrostate $k$.
This is done by the product of the Occupation Number $N_{jk}$ at Level $j$ in macrostate $k$, and the Total Number of Replicas in macrostate $k$.
Why is it that the Total Number of Replicas is the product of $\Delta N$ - the Number of Replicas that are in some microstate; with $W_k$ - the Number of Microstates included in the macrostate.
$$\Delta N \, W_k$$
I am considering a level $j$ with three states.  How would the above translate to this situation.

When you mention replicas, are you referring to the replica trick for glasses or just samples of the statistical ensemble?

By replicas I mean the number of times the system vibrates according to a specific microstate if measurements are taken at steps of $\delta t$.  I think I am getting towards a solution.
